# Error in getting data from MYSqL database

Tags: php, mysql, json

While i am retrieving the data including  special characters like “,” ‘ ’ — ? form MYSqL database in PHP file it is getting error like "no data found"..

The keyboard type characters are retrieving successsfully, but other than keyboard characters are not retrieving in PHP file.

I am trying to displaying the data in json response in PHP file.

So can any one tell me how to overcome form this..

Answer (score 3):

You need to use prepared statements to make it work with junk characters.

This is [documentation how to do this in PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

You should escape values passed trough mysql query with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use functions like htmlspecialchars()[THIS IS PHP SPECIFIC],mysql_real_escape_string() . they will solve your problems. Apart from solving your problems, they will provide extra security to your site which includes use of special symbols like SQL Injection etc.
what actually happens is when you use ' , " etc in your data, it completes the query in between as any '/" will end the query. So no data will be fetched.